# error when insert number via SQLloader

Tags: oracle, insert, sql-loader

I am trying to insert a numerical value into Oracle DB via SQL*loader but I still get the error:

> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table my_table, column column_1.
>   ORA-01722: invalid number

the line form SQL*loader which inserts the value is

```
column_1  INTEGER  "TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(:column_1, ' ', ''), '99999999D99')"
```

while the value I need to insert is: `30 000 000,00`

If I remove the mask (`'99999999D99'`), it inserts a number but is something wrong. The inserted value is: `807415859`

Can someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try changing the mask to '99 999 999D99' instead of doing the REPLACE? Your SQL*Loader line would then look like      -       column_1 INTEGER "TO_NUMBER(:column_1, '99 999 999D99')"

Comment: what's the *actual* text, that corresponds to the inserted value `807415859` ?

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar the actual value from .csv file is '30 000 000,00'

Comment: @vmachan: if I apply the change you mentioned, I have this error:
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table my_table, column column_1.
ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Answer (score 0):

After few more tests, the answer is:

```
column_1 "to_number(replace(replace(:column_1, ',', '.'), ' ', ','), '99999999.99')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the `TRANSLATE()` function easier.  Converts comma to period and space to NULL in one step.  Test like this:

```
SQL> select translate('30 000 000,00', ', ', '.') fixed
    from dual;

FIXED
-----------
30000000.00

SQL>
```

Full answer then:

```
column_1 "to_number(translate(:column_1, ', ', '.'), '99999999.99')"
```

Be sure to add a comment that the space needs to be last!